# Running a function with split loop in python

Tags: python, loops, split, time-complexity

I don't think I have given an appropriate Title for the question.

I have got a long sentence of integers with spaces between them. So, obviously I am using `.split()` method to have an array but the time complexity is a bit of an issue here. Actually, I am also looping this array I just created to solve my problem.

What I wanna do is, not have the loop twice - once in `.split()` and another one to solve the problem.
I just wanna know how can I not only split the sentences, but also use the **just** appended element in my algorithm.

Take this as an example:

```
prices = input().split()
days = int(input())

for day in range(days):
    i = int(input())
    count = 0
    for j in prices:
        if (i>=int(j)):
            count+=1
    print(count)
```

In this, I am first splitting the input and then again looping through the array later. I wanna use only one loop to do both of them to save time.

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Can't you try to convert the two for loops into one?

Comment: You are asking for user input in the loop, which means the outer look only runs as fast as a user can input. The inner loop, loops over the original user input, but in reality, how long can that really be. This seems like premature optimization. Are you really experiencing performance problems?

Comment: I would not even call it "premature optimization" - there is no way to optimize user input. To find an object for optimization - first `input()` inside cycle must be substituted with sequence with length equal to `days`

Comment: Don't focus on the input days but the input prices. prices kind of look like this : 2 3 5 10 199 354 133 13 ........ so, it is just one time input and then I am breaking that input into an array and then I am looping through that array later, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, asking for user input in the loop would be detrimental. But in case this is just a toy example, here is how you can improve your algorithm by not running linearly `O(n)` to the size of `prices` per loop but rather just `O(log n)`.

```
import bisect

prices = [10, 20, 15, 30, 35, 25, 30, 30]
days = 7
per_day = [8, 19, 35, 22, 13, 25, 30]

# Sort the prices so we can easily know how many are the greater items for a number
prices_sorted = sorted(prices)

for day in range(days):
    i = per_day[day]
    count = bisect.bisect(prices_sorted, i)  # Now, instead of traversing the prices linearly to count how many items are lesser than i, we just have to perform a binary search on where i would be placed in the sorted sequence.
    items = prices_sorted[:count]
    print(f"{i=} {count=} {items=}")
```

Output

```
i=8 count=0 items=[]
i=19 count=2 items=[10, 15]
i=35 count=8 items=[10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 30, 30, 35]
i=22 count=3 items=[10, 15, 20]
i=13 count=1 items=[10]
i=25 count=4 items=[10, 15, 20, 25]
i=30 count=7 items=[10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 30, 30]
```

Comment: I think I can't clearly clarify the question. First of all, you already have an array for prices and then you are trying to sort it. Even though your algo is faster, my question was not to have the time complexity of O(2n) when using split() and then looping through them. And probably I gave the wrong example for the question. But thanks anyway.